# ACPI BIOS Error (bug) black screen

Tags: dual-boot, acpi

I am new to Linux and just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I have this error:

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [^^^GFXO.AFN2], AE_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330).
```

I am unable to power off my Lenovo ideapad 330s laptop. Can anyone point me in the right direction?